# PostgreSQL - PSQL Client Hangs on almost any operation

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu-20.04

I've got PSQL Server (Tried 13 and 14)

A very basic setting. One small DB.

One user with password.

in pg_hba I have configured access from network (md5) to those databases.

When I connect from Server host everything is ok, I can do everything I want.
When I connect from remote machines (any) I successfully connected.
I can see databases, connection settings. Everything looks fine.
But when I just do "\dt" or many different things client hangs.

Nothing is doing, and it's not timing out.
I've stopped Server and this client didn't get this.

I'm using this on Ubuntu 20.04 most actual software available today.

Does anyone have idea what is going on?

On server side logs I can only see that client is lost and that is all.

Comment: You can try to test a local access doing the exact same subcommand, just to check, if it hangs again, you can isolate any client side issues. If so then try backuping your databases, drop them, stop the server, restart server, recreate databases & a fake table for testing it all from the start, if it works, it might be a bad character in some table name or database variables & so on. Else I do not have Idea to help you.

Comment: Issue has been solved. It was problem with mtu between client and server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was problem with MTU between client and server.